# Django accessing multiple databases dynamically

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a django project where I am trying to make a customer based grocery system. Here I have different databases for each customer.
Each database consist of order history as well as all other details like contact details etc.

I will get an url argument to identify customer through customer_id & I will able to get which database to use ie db name. Code -

Model -

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    db_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    db_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = DataFrameManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views file -

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def page(request, uuid):

if request.method == 'GET':
    rtrn = Company.objects.filter(db_uuid=uuid).values('db_name')
    return Response(rtrn)
```

Url file -

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'user/(?P<uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', page, name="getfromurl"), 

    ]
```

Here I will return db name.

But I am not able to understand and implement the change of database. Let me make you understand with an example -

Lets  suppose Customer name Gaurav has db 'gaurav_groceries'. By the code I get the name - gaurav_groceries. But in setting.py I have added default db as 'grocies', so how can I use this dynamic nature of db ie in this case we have 'gaurav_groceries', for further calculation and coding.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't trivially achieved. You may want to check out existing solutions, such as [Django-multitenant](https://github.com/citusdata/django-multitenant) which is currently the standard library used for building apps with tenanted DBs in Django.